# How to extract text between predefined strings in php

Tags: php, explode, gettext, substr

We're changing or translation system from GetText to MYSQL Database.
I want to put all the translations strings & translation ID from the original ".po" file into database.

For this I need to read the file and loop through each line, which is easy.
The difficult part is when I see "msgid" or "msgstr" I need to extract the datas and insert this into a database.

Original file looks like this :

```
msgid "inactive_ad_detail_text"
msgstr "This ad doesn't exists"
msgid "breadcrumb_search"
msgstr "Search the site"
(... etc etc ...)
```

How can I extract the name of the the id (msgid) and the text (msgstr) between quotation marks ?

Also, I have some escaped text and two lines text like :

```
msgid "question_fill_form"
msgstr ""
"Please fill the form"
"<br>All fields are mandatory"
```

**or**

```
msgid "offer_contact_error"
msgstr ""
"Error detected "
"please click \"<em>restart</em>\" on the right side."
```

I think I need to detect [msgid "] the the last ["] quotation mark before the end-of-line but I really have no clue how to achieve in PHP.

Thanks for you help,
Lio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a library for this. 
[PHP-po-parser](https://github.com/raulferras/PHP-po-parser)

```
// Parse a po file
$fileHandler = new Sepia\FileHandler('es.po');

$poParser = new Sepia\PoParser($fileHandler);
$entries  = $poParser->parse();
// $entries contains every entry in es.po file.

// Update entries
$msgid = 'Press this button to save';
$entries[$msgid]['msgstr'] = 'Pulsa este botón para guardar';
$poParser->setEntry($msgid, $entries[$msgid]);
// You can also change translator comments, code comments, flags...
```

If you don't use composer, you can include the files in order or use an autoloader to load these.

```
require_once('Sepia/InterfaceHandler.php');
require_once('Sepia/StringHandler.php');
require_once('Sepia/FileHandler.php');
require_once('Sepia/PoParser.php');
```

Comment: Thanks, a I don't use composer, what file do I need to include ?
include('/Sepia/PoParser.php');

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `file`, `strpos` and `substr` functions:

Let's say the input file `msgdata` has contents:

```
msgid "question_fill_form"
msgstr ""
"Please fill the form"
"<br>All fields are mandatory"
msgid "offer_contact_error"
msgstr ""
"Error detected "
"please click \"<em>restart</em>\" on the right side."
```

---

Consecutive processing:

```
$lines = file('msgdata');
$result = [];

foreach ($lines as $k => $line) {
    if (strpos($line, 'msgid') === 0) {
        $result[] = ['msgid' => substr($line, strpos($line, ' '))];
    } elseif (strpos($line, 'msgstr') === 0) {
        $result[count($result)-1]['msgstr'] = substr($line, strpos($line, ' '));
    } else {
        $result[count($result)-1]['msgstr'] .= $line;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [msgid] =>  "question_fill_form"

            [msgstr] =>  ""
"Please fill the form"
"
All fields are mandatory"

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [msgid] =>  "offer_contact_error"

            [msgstr] =>  ""
"Error detected "
"please click \"restart\" on the right side."
        )
)
```